# Comic book story about a Lion tamer who is injured then trains a gorilla

Tags: story-identification, comics

The story is about a circus lion tamer who is injured during a performance and told he can never train again but ends up training a gorilla who in a disguise trains lions. Not sure if it was in a DC or Marvel comic but I'm leaning towards DC.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Pendragon! See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12588/102999) for improving your question.

Comment: Around what year did you read it?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: So he can never train again, but he's capable of training a gorilla? He trains a gorilla instead of human apprentice? The gorilla somehow can pass for a human being despite its completely different build? And the gorilla is smart enough to train lions? So many questions.

Comment: memory is kind of fuzzy but maybe around 1960-1970? The premise was after being injured and being told he will never be able to train again he trains a gorilla to train lions to prove to them they were wrong, the gorilla is in a lion tamers suit and wears a helmet to hid who he is

Comment: Sounds like one of the origins of DC's Detective Chimp